# Sub array from a big array

Tags: php

I need to get a sub array from a big array (i dont know the array, it comes from the database), like this:

```
$array = 
  array(0=>'Name 1',1=>'Name 2',2=>'Name 3',3=>'Name 4',4=>'Name 5',5=>'Name 6');
```

What i need is to get the first 3 elements.

```
$new_array = array(0=>'Name 1',1=>'Name 2',2=>'Name 3');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$new_array = array_slice( $array, 0, 3);
```

Comment: Tnaks, this is what i was looking for!!

Answer (score 2):

you could also try `array_chunk()` to separate your array into small ones

Comment: `array_chunk($array,$x)` would return an array of x amount of arrays where x = `(count($array))/$x`