# Shifting and extracting from an array - php

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sub array from a big array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762135/sub-array-from-a-big-array)

Suppose I have an array with N entries. Given two integers n and m I am interested in entries from row n to row m. Suppose the value can only take two values val0 and val1

```
n => [val0]
n+1=> [val0]
n+2 => [val1]
...
m=> [val0]
```

I then want to extract a sub-array which returns, (a shift operator like) :

```
0 => [val0]
1 => [val0]
2 => [val1]
...
m-n => [val0]
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: Why m-n+1 and not m-n at the end?

Comment: @greg0ire you're right, I mistook

Comment: @gurudeb I tried to use array_shift but it does not the trick

Comment: I think you should use array_slice

Comment: array_slice() [http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php]

$subArray = array_slice($arr,0,4);

Answer (score 6):

Try the [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), passing `n` as offset and `m - n + 1` as limit

For more info see:
[Php Reference Manual - array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: Thank you, I should have find it!! Sorry